# (Cloudant) Creating a view to combine two document types

Tags: join, view, couchdb, cloudant, relational-algebra

Let's say that I'm making a Cloudant database to store all the service records for my fleet of cars (I'm not, but the problem is pretty much the same.) To do this, I have two types of records:

Cars:

```
  {
    "type": "Car",
    "_id": "VIN 1",
    "plateNumber": "ecto-1",
    "plateState": "NY",
    "make": "Cadillac",
    "model": "Professional Chassis",
    "year": 1959
  }

  {
    "type": "Car",
    "_id": "VIN 2",
    "plateNumber": "mntclmbr",
    "plateState": "VT",
    "make": "Jeep",
    "model": "Wrangler",
    "year": 2016
  }
```

And service records:

```
  {
    "type": "ServiceRecord",
    "_id": "service1",
    "carServiced": "VIN 1",
    "date": [1984, 6, 8],
    "item": "Cleaning (Goo)",
    "cost": 300
  }

  {
    "type": "ServiceRecord",
    "_id": "service2",
    "carServiced": "VIN 1",
    "date": [1984, 6, 9],
    "item": "Cleaning (Marshmellow)",
    "cost": 800
  }

  {
    "type": "ServiceRecord",
    "_id": "service3",
    "carServiced": "VIN 2",
    "date": [2016, 4, 2],
    "item": "Alignment",
    "cost": 150
  }
```

There's a couple things to note about how this works:

- The VIN number of a car will never change is used as the document _id.
- The service records for a car should not be lost if the car is registered in a new state, or with a new plate number.
- Due to the volume of cars, and how often they need repairs, it's not reasonable to edit a car's document if a service record needs to be added, removed, or changed.

Currently, I have a couple views to look up information.

First, I've got a map from license plate to VIN:

```
function(doc){
   if (doc.type == "Car"){
      emit([doc.plateState, doc.plateNumber], doc._id);
   }
}

// Results in:
["NY", "ecto-1"] -> "VIN 1"
["VT", "mntclmbr"] -> "VIN 2"
```

Second, I've got a map map from all the cars' VINs to the service records:

```
function(doc){
   if (doc.type == "ServiceRecord"){
      emit(doc.carServiced, doc);
   }
}

// Results in:
"VIN 1" -> {"_id": "service1", ...}
"VIN 1" -> {"_id": "service2", ...}
"VIN 2" -> {"_id": "service3", ...}
```

Finally, I've got a map map from all the cars' VINs and service dates to the specific service that happened on that date:

```
function(doc){
   if (doc.type == "ServiceRecord"){
      var key = [doc.carServiced, doc.date[0], doc.date[3], doc.date[2]];
      emit(key, doc);
   }
}

// Results in:
["VIN 1", 1984, 6, 8] -> {"_id": "service1", ...}
["VIN 1", 1984, 6, 9] -> {"_id": "service2", ...}
["VIN 2", 2016, 4, 2] -> {"_id": "service3", ...}
```

With these three maps, I can find three different things:

- The VIN of any car by its license plate.
- The service records of any car by its VIN.
- The service records of any car by its VIN for any particular year, month, or day.

However, *can't* find all the service records of a car by its license plate. (At least not in one step.) To do that, I would need a map like this:

```
["NY", "ecto-1"] -> {"_id": "service1", ...}
["NY", "ecto-1"] -> {"_id": "service2", ...}
["VT", "mntclmbr"] -> {"_id": "service3", ...}
```

And to make it even MORE complicated, I'd like to be able to look up service records by license plate AND date, with a map like this:

```
["NY", "ecto-1", 1984, 6, 8] -> {"_id": "service1", ...}
["NY", "ecto-1", 1984, 6, 9] -> {"_id": "service2", ...}
["VT", "mntclmbr", 2016, 4, 2] -> {"_id": "service3", ...}
```

Unfortunately, I don't know how to generate maps like these because the key requires information from two documents. I can only get plate information from Car documents and I can only get service information (including the document _id for the value of emit) from ServiceRecord documents.

So far, my only thought is to do two queries: one to get the VIN from the plate info, and another to get the service records from the VIN. They'll be fast queries, so it's not a huge problem, but I feel like there's a better way.

Anyone know what that better way might be?

(Bonus: The two-query method does not allow for finding all service records by state in an efficient way. The last map I describe would be able to do that. So bonus internet-points for anyone who can describe a solution that provides that functionality as well.)

**Edit: Another issue, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3365268/how-can-i-call-another-view-in-a-couchdb-view), was suggested as a possible duplicate. It is definitely a similar problem, however the solutions provided do not solve this issue. Specifically, the top solution suggests storing an document's position within the tree. In this case, that would be something like `"index":[State, Number, Year, Month, Day]"` in a ServiceRecord document. However, we can't do that because the plate information can easily change.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can i call another view in a couchdb view?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3365268/how-can-i-call-another-view-in-a-couchdb-view)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hopefully you are still around. The gist of the answer is : in CouchDb when you feel a need to do joins you are 99% of the times doing something wrong. What you need to do is have all the information you need in one document.

You need to get into the habit of thinking about how you are going to query your data when you design what to save. You will find that replacing the "relational normalization" habit with this habit is healthy.

What you can do here is save the licence plate number in the service record document. Don't be afraid to denormalize. A service record should therefore look like this :

```
{
    "type": "ServiceRecord",
    "_id": "service3",
    "carServiced": "VIN 2",
    "carPlateNumber": "mntclmbr", 
    "date": [2016, 4, 2],
    "item": "Alignment",
    "cost": 150
}
```

And you can easily do whatever you want from here. That being said, the architect I am can smell that you are likely to invent new ways to query this data every month. For this reason, I'd personally prefer to store the whole car document within the service record :

```
{
    "type": "ServiceRecord",
    "_id": "service3",
    "carServiced":  {
        "type": "Car",
        "_id": "VIN 2",
        "plateNumber": "mntclmbr",
        "plateState": "VT",
        "make": "Jeep",
        "model": "Wrangler",
        "year": 2016
      }, 
   "date": [2016, 4, 2],
        "item": "Alignment",
        "cost": 150
}
```

This is absolutely fine. Especially since a service record is a snapshot in time and you do not need to worry about updating the information. I actually find that this is one of the scenarios where CouchDb particularly shines as storing a snapshot basically is a free lunch (as opposed to managing a cars_snapshot table in a relational system). And we tend to forget it but very often (especially as far as sales are concerned), we are interested in snapshots, not up-to-date relational data (what was the customer name at the time he bought, what was the tax rate at the time he bought, etc.). But relational systems put us in the "most up to date by default" habit because snapshot management involves a significant overhead there.

The bottom line is that this kind of denormalization is absolutely fine in CouchDb. You are in the intended usage and won't be bitten in the back down the road. As CouchDb puts it : just relax ;)

Comment: This is a great answer. One caveat is that, for my actual problem, the analogue to the "ServiceRecord" here *does* need to be updated. For example, if the Jeep in my example gets a new license plate "rollovr", then all the service records for that vehicle would have to be updated. Because it's necessary to be able to find every service record a vehicle has ever had, even if the vehicle is reregistered. (Hence why I was trying to track by VIN, which won't change.)

Comment: The solution I've implemented is a middle ground between the two. There are still "Car" documents with general information about a group, and "ServiceRecord" documents with specific information about a member of that group. Then each "ServiceRecord" has an `indexKey` field, such as `{"_id":"VIN 2", "plateNumber": "mntclmbr", "plateState":"VT"}`, for indexing. In the semi-rare event that a car is re-registered, we can search for and update all the service records with the updated plate information. So, inefficient (but rare) updates in exchange for very efficient (and common) lookups.

Comment: I'm glad you found it helpful ! One thought would be that perhaps the plateState could be its own document and look like : `{ id: plateState1, plateText: 'ASF256' }`, and then the car would reference the plateState like this `{ id: 'car1', plateStateId: 'plateState1' }` so that you never have to do a bulk update. But ! We are back to a 2-queries solution. But this addresses the issue you mentioned with querying by state, and as you mentioned the queries would be very fast. You'd have the views : `getPlateIdByPlateText/State`, and `getServicedCarByPlateId`

Comment: Yep! For our API, I've wound up with endpoints that look like `/api/lookup/byVIN/:vin` or `/api/lookup/byPlate/:plateState/:plateNumber` to find a car, and `/api/lookup/byVIN/:vin/[all|latest|:serviceDate]` or `/api/lookup/byPlate/:plateState/:plateNumber/[all|latest|:serviceDate]` to find service record(s). All the GET endpoints only need one Cloudant query. Some of the POST endpoints need two, but those are expected to be rare and should be quite acceptable.

Comment: There is Best practices documents that state: Split data into many small documents depending on how often and when data changes. https://github.com/jo/couchdb-best-practices#document-modeling-to-avoid-conflicts (One to N relations are also described)

Answer (score -1):

It sounds like chained mapreduce could provide your solution? 
https://examples.cloudant.com/sales/_design/sales/index.html

Comment: I got super excited when I started reading through this link, because it looked promising. Unfortunately, because it's a reduce function, you can only get aggregated data. So, for example, I might be able to use it to calculate the total repair costs, by license plate, but not a list of all the service records themselves. (At least, not without a *massive* storage and performance penalty.)

Comment: James did you note the `dbcopy` option, where you're copying the view to a new database? Using that strategy you can do what you want even if you have to create a situation where the reduce step doesn't actually do anything. That would result in a storage "penalty" but not a performance one maybe?

Comment: I've tried a couple different approaches with `dbcopy`, but I can't figure out any way to get the data I need into a single document to build a view on.

It's quite possible I'm just not understanding properly. Could you give an example of what my map and reduce functions might look like?

Comment: This link is to a private password protected page.